# Upgrading from 4.6.4 to 4.6.6 returns following error, how to go pass it?

Tags: upgrade

[image: error message]

Although I have followed all the steps listed in the upgrade tutorial, this is the message comes up in the beginning of the upgrading process. I have tried on my demo & production site, both have same error. how to fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Failed Upgrade 4.6.4 to 4.6.5 Joomla 2.5 & 3.4](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4387/failed-upgrade-4-6-4-to-4-6-5-joomla-2-5-3-4). Let us know whether the procedure described there solves the problem.